# перемещение виджетов по QHBoxLayout PyQt

Tags: python, pyqt, qlayout, qpushbutton, qhboxlayout

Я столкнулся с проблемой.
Есть некий виджет, который в конструкторе принимает список других виджетов,  которые надо на нём разместить. Ничего лучше, кроме как кинуть их на слой я не придумал.

Суть вопроса такова: каким образом я могу манипулировать своими виджетами на слое (перемещать etc.)

Может быть вам известен лучший способ закрепления виджетов на другом виджете, но обязательно так, чтобы их можно было передвигать (т.е. `QGridLayout` не подходит).
Заранее благодарю за помощь

Код большого виджета:

```
class playingField(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, forms): #forms - список маленьких виджетов
        super().__init__()
        self.forms = self.set_forms(forms)
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.set_color()
        self.set_layout()

    def set_color(self):
        self.setAutoFillBackground(True)
        appearance = self.palette()
        appearance.setColor(QPalette.Normal, QPalette.Window, QColor("purple"))
        self.setPalette(appearance)

    def set_forms(self, forms):
        res = []
        for i in range(5):
            res.append(forms[i])
        return res

    def set_layout(self):
        layout = QHBoxLayout()
        for i in range(5):
            layout.addWidget(self.forms[i])
        w = layout.itemAt(0).widget() #маленький виджет можно получить так
        w.move(100, 200)         #но подвигать его не получается
        layout.replaceWidget(layout.itemAt(0).widget(), w) #тут я даже подумал заменять маленькие виджеты 
        self.setLayout(layout)
```

Comment: Скажите пожалуйста, предыдущий вопрос, который вы задавали, решен или нет?

Comment: Да, решён, забыл вас поблагодарить

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я вам советую не бросать идею заменять маленькие виджеты. Просто запустите мой пример и понаблюдайте что происходит.

```
from PyQt5.QtCore    import *
from PyQt5.QtGui     import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from random import randint

class playingField(QWidget):
    def __init__(self): 
        super().__init__()

        self.setAutoFillBackground(True)
        appearance = self.palette()
        appearance.setColor(QPalette.Normal, QPalette.Window, QColor("purple"))
        self.setPalette(appearance)
        self.lenForms = 0

        timer = QTimer(self, timeout=self.changeWidget, interval=2000)
        timer.start()

    def set_layout(self, forms):                  # + forms - список маленьких виджетов
        self.lenForms = len(forms)
        self.layout = QHBoxLayout(self)                
        for w in forms:
            self.layout.addWidget(w)

    # тут я даже подумал заменять маленькие виджеты, продолжайте думать :)     
    def changeWidget(self):
        f = randint(0, self.lenForms-1)
        t = randint(0, self.lenForms-2)
        while f == t:
            t = randint(0, self.lenForms-2)

        wFrom = self.layout.itemAt(f).widget()
        wTo   = self.layout.itemAt(t).widget()
        wReplace = self.layout.replaceWidget(wFrom, wTo)

        if not wReplace is None:
            n = randint(0, self.layout.count()-1)
            self.layout.insertWidget(n, wReplace.widget()) 
        else:
            self.layout.addWidget(wTo)    


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication([])                

    w = playingField()
    w.set_layout( (QPushButton("111", w, minimumSize=QSize(70, 70), maximumSize=QSize(70, 70)), 
            QPushButton("222", w, minimumSize=QSize(70, 70), maximumSize=QSize(70, 70),
                        styleSheet="background-color:green;"), 
            QPushButton("333", w, minimumSize=QSize(70, 70), maximumSize=QSize(70, 70),
                        styleSheet="background-color:yellow;"), 
            QPushButton("444", w, minimumSize=QSize(70, 70), maximumSize=QSize(70, 70),
                        styleSheet="background-color:red;"), 
            QPushButton("555", w, minimumSize=QSize(70, 70), maximumSize=QSize(70, 70),
                        styleSheet="background-color:blue;"),) )

    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

```
import sys
from random import randint
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QHBoxLayout


class App(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setGeometry(300, 200, 500, 200)
        self.setWindowTitle("Пример перемещения виджетов")
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: white;")

        self.button = QPushButton(self)
        self.button.setFixedSize(100, 50)
        self.button.setText("Двигать виджет")
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.move_button)

        layout = QHBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)



    def move_button(self):
        x, y = randint(0, 400), randint(0, 180)
        self.button.move(x, y)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app = App()
    app.show()
    sys.exit(run.exec_())
```

Comment: Я пробовал метод move, но желаемого результата не получил

Comment: Вопрос обновите

Comment: Я вам показал пример перемещение виджетов

Comment: PyQt5 поддерживает drag and drop если что

Comment: мб я неправильно сформулировал, мне хотелось бы узнать можно ли как-то перемещать виджеты, находящиеся в layout'-е а не просто созданные в главном виджете

Comment: А BoxLalout move не работает или что ?

Comment: ну вот я это и хочу узнать, потому что взяв элемент взятый из BoxLayout не двигается

Comment: Обновил ответ  --------------------------------------

Comment: окей, действительно работает, значит буду разбираться в своем коде, спасибо

Comment: Может вам ещё и понравился мой ответ?)